# alternatives to unescape() deprecated method?

Tags: javascript, escaping, uri, decode, deprecated

What are some alternatives to the `unesacpe()` method? I know `decodeURI` and `decodeURIComponent` are some that are listed online. However what if I have a string like
`test%20test%`? Calling `decodeURIComponent` on that would just result in a uri error instead of "test test%". I would like to use `unescape` but its been deprecated. What else can I do?

Comment: "_Calling `decodeURIComponent` on that would just result in `"test%20test%"`_": That's not correct: `decodeURIComponent("test%20test%")` results in a [`URIError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/URIError) exception being thrown. Even `unescape("test%20test%")` results in `"test test%"` which is not what you stated that you want. Did you test this? If so, what environment did you use?

Comment: @jsejcksn ah yes sorry got mixed up with some other stuff; using `decodeURIComponent` results in a uri error. But no "test test%" is what I want

Comment: What's the exact behavior that you want? Just replacement of `"%20"` with `" "`? That's simple: `"test%20test%".replaceAll("%20", " ")`. If you want another behavior, you must specify what exactly it is that you expect.

Comment: @jsejcksn well no not really; I want to do exactly what the `unescape` method does. Replace all escape sequences, and was wondering if there was a pre-existing method out there that does what the `unescape` method does

Comment: Why do you care about this? You should only do this when the string is the result of proper escaping. `test%20test%` should never be an input string.